# Autoboxing: type mismatch can't cast int to Integer

Tags: java

My eclipse's compiler compliance level is set to 1.7 but i am still getting the above error. why it's so?

The code is:

```
public Integer next(){
    Integer i = nextnode.item; // nextnode.item is giving int
    nextnode = nextnode.next;
    return i;
}
```

I will appreciate your help.

Comment: Is `Integer` a type variable?

Comment: Please show the smallest runnable code example that demonstrates the problem. For example, what is `nextnode`?

Comment: what do you mean by type variable? @SotiriosDelimanolis

Comment: actually i am implementing linked list  where nextnode is the object(node) of a class node which contains instance variables: item(int) and next(node). But i stucked at this point

Comment: Just do what Jason asked.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, the best I can suggest is using [`Integer.valueOf(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28int%29) (Java 1.5+) that way your code should work and you can look into your project compiler level at your leisure like

```
Integer i = Integer.valueOf(nextnode.item);
```

Answer (score 0):

This class doesn't compile.

```
class MyClass<Integer> {

    public Integer method() {
        return 42;
    }
}
```

The reason it doesn't compile is that `Integer` doesn't have its usual meaning because we are using it as the name of a type parameter. Usually we use a one letter name like `T` or `E`.

Just get rid of `<Integer>` and it compiles.

Comment: how is this relevant to the OP's question?

Comment: @ScaryWombat It answers it. The OP's question was "why am I getting the message can't cast int to Integer". This is probably why.